# Android - Netty - RejectedExecutionException

Tags: netty, nio

Im am back with a tricky question.

I have written a netty server for our Android Project but SOMETIMES, when i try to send something to the connected Clients, i get an RejectedExecutionException.

> 03-17 22:07:49.938  21708-22346/htlhallein.at.serverdatenbrille_rewritten E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-9824
>       Process: htlhallein.at.serverdatenbrille_rewritten, PID: 21708
>       java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: event executor terminated
>               at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.reject(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:707)
>               at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.addTask(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:299)
>               at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.execute(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:690)
>               at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.register(AbstractChannel.java:421)
>               at io.netty.channel.SingleThreadEventLoop.register(SingleThreadEventLoop.java:60)
>               at io.netty.channel.SingleThreadEventLoop.register(SingleThreadEventLoop.java:48)
>               at io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup.register(MultithreadEventLoopGroup.java:64)
>               at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap.initAndRegister(AbstractBootstrap.java:315)
>               at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap.doBind(AbstractBootstrap.java:271)
>               at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap.bind(AbstractBootstrap.java:267)
>               at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap.bind(AbstractBootstrap.java:242)
>               at htlhallein.at.serverdatenbrille_rewritten.server.DatenbrillenServer$Server.run(DatenbrillenServer.java:172)
>               at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

I am not sure which Event Executor i should take?
The Exception gets fired a line after running the server. (Log.d(DatenbrillenServer.class.toString(), "Stopped Server ...");)

Did anyone have an Idea, why this happens ?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens when you try to do an IO after you called shutdownGracefully(). Be sure you are done with all IO before calling it

Comment: Tank you!
I also used 4.0.26 Final, but you added official Android support in Version 4.1+
And i moved the server.stop() from the android stop event to the destroy event.
Now it is working like a charme!